# How would I make this python script keep running and not just stop after running once?

Tags: python, boot, rpi.gpio, pi-3

Im working on a game for my RPi3 B running raspbian, whenever I run this py script from the command line it runs once and stops, I would like it to stay open and keep running as it waits for a knock sensor to be knocked.. I am new to python if that helps. When the script detects a knock sensor it sends a value (Strike 1) to my sqlite db. I then retrieve that data using php and ajax into my browser running from my local apache server. It all works if I run the py script first in idle as it stays open but not from the command line..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sqlite3

KnockPin = 12 

print ("Welcome to Bases Loaded")

def setstr():
    global strikes
    strikes = 0

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)         
    GPIO.setup(KnockPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def knock(ev=None):

    with sqlite3.connect('/var/www/html/basesLoaded.db') as conn:

        global strikes
        strikes += 1

        if strikes ==0:
            pass
        elif strikes == 1:

            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set STRIKE = 1 WHERE ID =1");

            print ("Strike 1 :", conn.total_changes);

        elif strikes == 2:

            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set STRIKE = 2 WHERE ID=1");

            print ("Strike 2 :", conn.total_changes);

        elif strikes == 3:
            conn.execute("UPDATE bl set STRIKE = 0 WHERE ID=1");
            print ("Strike 3 Your Out :", conn.total_changes);
            setstr()


def register_callbacks():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(KnockPin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=knock, bouncetime=2500) 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        setup()
        register_callbacks()

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        destroy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question if really off-topic as it is nothing specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Put a while forever loop after the call to register_callbacks.  The loop needs to do nothing more than time.sleep(1).  At the moment the program terminates after the register_callbacks call.

Comment: Thanks for the simple tip, now it works! I can launch the py file from my browser now using php!